# Quartz Scheduler trigger 4 times a day

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

i want to run my **Quartz** job 4 times all day and i am using cron job to trigger my job and have provided value in xml. Please let me know the **Quartz Expression** so that i can trigger my job 4 times all day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
0 0 0/6 * * ?
```

This will fire at 0:00, 6:00, 12:00 and 18:00. If you want a different offset time, e.g. first invocation at 3:45:

```
0 45 3/6 * * ?
```

Check out [JavaDoc of `CronTrigger`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html). But in your case a simple trigger will be... well, simpler:

```
trigger = newTrigger()
  .startNow()
  .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
    .withIntervalInHours(6)
    .repeatForever())
  .build();
```

Note that the semantics aren't exactly the same. The former trigger reflects DST so it will always fire at the same wall clock time.